# Android WebView app reload the url forever

Tags: java, android, webview

I’ve create this Web View app, but something doesn’t work well. The page is reloaded over and over again. Could you help me to find why it is happens ?

I think this happens when it try to load the body content of the url.

```
package com.maunexus;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private WebView webView;
Activity activity;
private ProgressDialog progDailog;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

    webView=findViewById(R.id.webviewid);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl("https://pari365.mg");

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.super_menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}



@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.menu_back:
            onBackPressed();
            break;

        case R.id.menu_forward:
            onForwardPressed();
            break;

        case R.id.menu_refresh:
            webView.reload();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Reloading... Please Wait!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;


    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


private void onForwardPressed(){
    if (webView.canGoForward()){
        webView.goForward();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Already there! ;)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

public void onBackPressed(){
    if (webView.canGoBack()){
        webView.goBack();
    }
}
}
```

There’s sometimes when the refresh is not happening, but the url does not load in full.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add this line of code for accepting thirdparty cookies

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webView,true);
    }
```

It will work like a charm

Comment: Hm... I'm thinking where I should add this "if". Also, "Build:" and "Cookie Manager" cannot be resolved.

Comment: @Adrian add it after webView=findViewById(R.id.webviewid); other wise it will give null pointer exception